# getting an div ID, passing to a variable, then unhiding that div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I'm trying to capture a button ID and to pass it to a function that associates it with a div that has the same value. I want to then dynamically have jquery change the css on that div.

Everything works (I can dynamically create the div ID and show it, but it won't the background to yellow.) In the long run I want to have "display: none" that appear as you click on the provided buttons.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="parent" id="level_0">Intro Level 
<br></br>
<input type="button" id="level_1a" value="Choice A"            onclick="set_path(this.id);"> 
<input type="button" id="level_1b" value="Choice B" onclick="set_path(this.id);">
<br></br>
    <div class="child" id="level_1az">This is Level 1 A
    </div>

    <div class="child" id="level_1bz">This is Level 1 B
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fill-in"></div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
function set_path(clicked_id) {
   var divX = ('#' + clicked_id);
   var divID = "'"+divX+"'";
   document.getElementById('fill-in').innerHTML = divID;
   $(divID).css("background-color", "yellow");
};
```

You can see the code here: http://codepen.io/cunyj/pen/qdrYxe/

Comment: You sure you have loaded jQuery in your codepen? Also, your divs have an extra `z` suffixed to the IDs but while concatenating, you haven't taken that into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're **not using** the **jQuery library** in your codepen`
2. Your level IDs have an additional `"z"` like `level_1az` so you might want to:

***[Demo that uses jQuery](http://jsbin.com/xepiza/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
function set_path(clicked_id) {
   var divX = ('#' + clicked_id);
   $('fill-in').html( divX );
   $(divX+'z').css("background-color", "yellow"); // use that 'z'
}
```

***[Demo in pure JavaScript](http://jsbin.com/xepiza/2/edit)***

```
function set_path(clicked_id) {
   var divX = clicked_id;
   document.getElementById('fill-in').innerHTML = divX;
   var level = document.getElementById(divX +'z'); // use that 'z'
   level.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Roko. You're right about the added z. I thought that maybe it didn't like having the same id twice but that didn't seem to be the problem and i forgot to change it back. Very helpful.

Comment: @user1922698 you're welcome. PS: you **cannot** have multiple IDs on the same page, so using another character like you did - *is correct*. Otherwise it's like two persons having the same insurance ID number ;)